# What is the point of pass and listen in Writer monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I have been learning about monads in the book [learnyouahaskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).
After reading about the writer monad, I decided to check the documentation of the [Control.Monad.Writer.Class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Writer-Class.html).

There I saw that they also implemented the `listen` and `pass` functions but I was not able to understand what they are used for. Could someone give me a good example so I can understand how to use `listen` and `pass`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is code from `Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.Strict` that defined `listen` and `pass`:

```
listen :: (Monoid w, Monad m) => WriterT w m a -> WriterT w m (a, w)
listen m = WriterT $ do
    (a, w) <- runWriterT m
    return ((a, w), w)

pass :: (Monoid w, Monad m) => WriterT w m (a, w -> w) -> WriterT w m a
pass m = WriterT $ do
    ((a, f), w) <- runWriterT m
    return (a, f w)
```

`WriterT` is a monad transformer which provides `Writer` functionality to other monads, the simple `Writer` type is defined as  `type Writer w = WriterT w Identity`, in `Identity` monad the bind function (`<-` and `>>=`) is just variable binding, so if we break down the monadic part of the code above:

```
listen :: (Monoid w) => Writer w a -> Writer w (a, w)
listen m = Writer $
    let (a, w) = runWriter m
    in ((a, w), w)

pass :: (Monoid w) => Writer w (a, w -> w) ->　Writer w a
pass m = Writer $
    let ((a, f), w) = runWriter m
    in (a, f w)
```

It's now clear that `listen` gives you access to the log produced by a Writer action inside the Writer monad, and `pass` gives you a way to alter the log inside the Writer monad.

Assume you have a `Writer [String]` and want to log an action only if the log produced by it satisfies some condition:

```
deleteOn :: (Monoid w) => (w -> Bool) -> Writer w a -> Writer w a
deleteOn p m = pass $ do
    (a, w) <- listen m
    if p w
        then return (a, id)
        else return (a, const mempty)

-- Or pass alone
deleteOn' :: (Monoid w) => (w -> Bool) -> Writer w a -> Writer w a
deleteOn' p m = pass $ do
    a <- m
    return (a, (\w -> if p w then mempty else w))

logTwo :: Writer [String] ()
logTwo = do
    deleteOn ((> 5) . length . head) $ tell ["foo"]
    deleteOn ((> 5) . length . head) $ tell ["foobar"]
{-
*Main> runWriter logTwo
((),["foo"])
-}
```

Comment: If it's a duplicate, flag the post. When you have over 250 rep, you can also vote to close a question as a duplicate (needs 5 votes). I removed the "this is a duplicate" part, since it's not necessary for your (otherwise well-written) answer.

Answer (score 6):

Inside a `Writer` you can't inspect what has been written, until you run (or "unwrap") the monad, using `execWriter` or `runWriter`. However, you can use `listen` to inspect what some sub-action wrote to the writer, before the value is appended to the writer state, and you can use `pass` to modify what is written.

Consider this example of an application that uses `WriterT` for logging:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer

-- Monad stack for the application uses IO, wrapped in a logging WriterT
type App a = WriterT [String] IO a

-- utility to write to the log
logMsg :: String -> App ()
logMsg msg = tell [msg]

-- gets an Int from user input (and logs what it does)
getInt :: App Int
getInt = do
    logMsg "getting data"
    n <- liftIO getLine
    logMsg $ "got line: " ++ show n
    return . read $ n

-- application logic that uses getInt and increments the result by 1
app :: App Int
app = do
    n <- getInt
    return $ n + 1

-- main code runs the application and prints the log
main = do
    (res, logs) <- runWriterT app
    print $ "Result = " ++ show res
    putStrLn "Log: "
    mapM_ putStrLn logs
```

Now, for some reason, inside `app`, I want to know what messages `getInt` wrote to the log. I can do that with `listen`:

```
app :: App Int
app = do
    (n, logs) <- listen getInt
    let numLogLines = length logs
    logMsg $ "getInt logged " ++ show numLogLines ++ " lines"
    return $ n + 1
```